# GDB internal error when using clone()

Tags: gdb, clone

I'm working on Ubuntu 12.04 and debugging the below code using gdb. I get the following internal error whenever calling `clone()`.

```
34      pid = clone(entryPt,(char*)pStack+stackSize,SIGCHLD|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_VM,&arg);
(gdb) n
/build/buildd/gdb-7.4-2012.04/gdb/linux-thread-db.c:418: internal-error: thread_get_info_callback: Assertion `inout->thread_info != NULL' failed.
A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
further debugging may prove unreliable.
Quit this debugging session? (y or n)
```

Here is the code segment.

```
int taskSpawn(char* name, int priority, int option, int stackSize, FUNCPTR entryPt, int arg)
{
    TblEntry            *Task_Entry;
    int                 Handle, q_idx, old_idx, old_priority;
    void                *pStack;
    pid_t               pid = 0; // to be modified.
    struct _Task        *new_TCB, *old_TCB;
    /* Get a free entry */
    Handle  =   _CreateHandle(&Task_Entry);

    if( Handle == -1 )
        return -1; // fail to spawn task.

    pStack = malloc(stackSize);
    // Call clone().
#ifdef __linux
    pid = clone(entryPt,
                (char*)pStack+stackSize,
                SIGCHLD|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_VM,
                &arg);
    kill(pid, SIGSTOP);
    printf("clone returns %d\n", pid);

    if(pid < 0)
    {
        exit(0);
    }

#endif
return 0;
}
```

why does `clone()` give me this error?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might like to also show `entryPt()`.

Comment: FUNCPTR is just `int`. caller passes a function name as `entryPt`.

Comment: If "*`FUNCPTR` is just `int`*" that might be the cause for the crash, as it shall be `int (*)(void *)`. Also it might very well be, that it's not `clone()` that crashes but `entryPt()`, as it's startet by `clone()`. However it's just a guess as you hide `entryPt()` from us.

Answer (score 0):

It's not your fault. It's a bug in GDB: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18006